# How to query one-to-many relationship in JPQL?

Tags: jpa, jpql

There is a user entity having one-to-many relationship with role entity. In other words, one user can have multiple roles. Anyhow when I query using JPQL, the Role entity is showing duplicate results, in this case, it shows `ROLE_ADMIN` twice. When I debug the code, I can see that the Role entity is having same memory id:

```
[org.huahsin.Role@1b332d22, org.huahsin.Role@1b332d22]
```

I wasn't sure whether I have did something wrong in JPQL. Please correct me if I'm wrong. The following are some hints on this problem.

---

This is the content available in Users table:

```
+----------+----------+---------+
| username | password | enabled |
+----------+----------+---------+
| user7    | user7    |       1 |
+----------+----------+---------+
```

This is the table description for Users table:

```
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| username | varchar(10) | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| password | varchar(32) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| enabled  | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

This is the content available in Authority table:

```
+----------+------------+
| username | authority  |
+----------+------------+
| user7    | ROLE_ADMIN |
| user7    | ROLE_USER  |
+----------+------------+
```

This is the table description for Authority table:

```
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| username  | varchar(10) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| authority | varchar(10) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

This is the query on User entity:

```
@NamedQuery(
        name="findByUser",
        query="select u from User u where u.username in (select r.userId from u.roleList r where r.userId = :username)")
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User {

    @Id
    private String username;

    private String password;

    private Integer enabled;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Role.class, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name="username")
    private List<Role> roleList;
```

This is the Role Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="authority")
public class Role {

    @Id
    @Column(name="username")
    private String userId;

    @Column(name="authority")
    private String role;
```

This is how I retrieve the results:

```
List<User> l = emf.createEntityManager().createNamedQuery("findByUser", User.class).setParameter("username", username).getResultList();
for( User u : l ) {
    System.out.println(u.getUsername());
    System.out.println(u.getRoleList());
}
```

Comment: When you debug the code, you see the same Role entry twice. Where do you see them? Also: consider making the relationship bilateral and hashing the passwords in DB.

Comment: @AndreiI I have update on the code listing at the end of the question.

Comment: This is pretty clear to me: this means that in your DB you have the same Role associated twice.

Comment: @AndreiI May I know how did you know whether I have same Role associated twice?

Comment: Because entry `org.huahsin.Role@1b332d22` was displayed twice (that number after @ is a hashCode). Was I right with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- It's not clear what you are trying to achieve by this query. If you want to load a user by its `username`, and `username` is a primary key, you can do it as follows:

  ```
  User u = em.find(User.class, username);
  ```
- You get incorrect results because your `Role` entity is mapped incorrectly: `userId` is annotated as `@Id`, but it's not a primary key (i.e. it's not unique).

I'd suggest you to change the database schema. A many-to-many relationship between `User` and `Role` (with join table) would be much easier to map:

```
public class User {
    ...
    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "users_authority")
    private List<Role> roleList;
    ...
}

public class Role {
    @Id 
    private String authority;
}
```

If the current database schema is fixed, you'll need to:

- Express the fact that `authority` has composite key (`username`, `authority`) using `@EmbeddedId`
- Make your relationship bidirectional
- Use `@MapsId` to indicate the fact that foreign key `authority`(`username`) is a part of the composite key of `authority`

**See also:**

- [`@MapsId`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/MapsId.html)

Comment: I have added the table description in my question. It shows that I have a primary key in user table and a foreign key in authority table. These 2 tables using `username` as the key to establish a relationship.

Comment: You got the point, `userId` is annotated as @Id but it's not a primary key. I got this problem solved by adding a new primary key column into Role entity. Great help.